# How to fix "popup div hide immediately" after ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I wrote an ajax function where on blur the input values are written to the DB, but one input needs to run through two ajax functions:

1. The first ajax creates a row and checks for duplicates (if a duplicate exist then popup an alert div, if not, see duplicate its only update)
2. The second ajax updates a row (if a duplicate exists, popup alert div, if not, see duplicate its only update).

Problem is that after the ajax executes the alert popup (div), it shows and immediately closes. When the second time focus and blur happen on that input all is OK. On hide no problems.

I realise that the problem is when `setTimeout()` or `hide()` are present and run twice. When they run once, then all is OK.

In my code both `setTimeout()` and `hide()` are present.

If I delete the `setTimeout()` then it's working, but it's closed immediately. I need a delay for a few seconds to show the success message. I tried adding a delay: but no luck.

If I try `bind('hide')`, `unbind('hide')`, then only the popup appears and no auto hide is happening.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input1,  .input2, .input3, .input4, .input5, .input6").blur(function() {
        inv_header_footer_ajax(function result_inv(data){
           if(data == 1){
                $('.alert-icon-3').removeClass('fa-warning').addClass('fa-check').css("background-color", "green");
                setTimeout(function () { 
                    $('#alert-popup-3').hide(function() {
                        $('#alert-popup-3').removeClass('alert-show');
                        $('#alert-popup-content-3').text('Successful');
                    });
                }, 4000);
                document.getElementById("input5").style.borderColor = "";  
             } else {
                $('.alert-icon-3').removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-warning').css("background-color", "red");
                $('#alert-popup-3').show(function() {
                    $('#alert-popup-3').addClass('alert-show');
                    $('#alert-popup-content-3').text('Allert INV !!!');
                });
                document.getElementById("input5").style.borderColor = "red";
            }
        }); 
        inv_rows_ajax();
        inv_kpo_ajax();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var q = document.getElementById("input1");
    var w = document.getElementById("input1");
    q.addEventListener("blur", insert_update_kpo_row);
    w.addEventListener("blur", kpo_check);   

    function kpo_check(){
        inv_kpo_ajax(function result_kpo(data){
            if(data == 1){
                $('.alert-icon-4').removeClass('fa-warning').addClass('fa-check').css("background-color", "green");
                setTimeout(function () { 
                    $('#alert-popup-4').hide(function() {
                        $('#alert-popup-4').removeClass('alert-show');
                        $('#alert-popup-content-4').text('Successful');
                    });
                }, 4000);
                document.getElementById("input1").style.borderColor = "";
            } else {
                $('.alert-icon-4').removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-warning').css("background-color", "red");
                $('#alert-popup-4').show(function() {
                    $('#alert-popup-4').addClass('alert-show');
                    $('#alert-popup-content-4').text('Allert KPO !!!');
                });
                document.getElementById("input1").style.borderColor = "red";
            }
        });
    };

    function insert_update_kpo_row() {
        $.confirm({
            attachOnlyOnce: true,
            type: 'orange',
            boxWidth: '39%',
            useBootstrap: false,
            theme: 'material',
            icon: 'fa fa-warning',
            title: 'font-awesome',
            title: 'Warning?',
            content: 'Create KPO row??',
            buttons: { 
                Yes:  { 
                    btnClass: 'btn-orange',
                    action: function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"php/insert_order_row_to_db.php",
                            method:"POST",
                            dataType:"json",
                            success:function(data){
                                $("#last_id_kpo").val(data);
                                inv_kpo_ajax(function result_kpo(data){
                                    if(data == 1){
                                    } else {
                                        $('.alert-icon-4').removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-warning').css("background-color", "red");
                                        $('#alert-popup-4').show(function() {
                                            $('#alert-popup-4').addClass('alert-show');
                                            $('#alert-popup-content-4').text('Allert KPO !!!');
                                        });
                                        document.getElementById("input1").style.borderColor = "red";
                                    }
                                });
                                document.getElementById("input1").removeEventListener("blur", insert_update_kpo_row);
                            }
                        });  
                    },
                }, 
                No: {}, 
            },
        });
    };
});
```

I need that when `input1` triggers `blur` that the first ajax runs with `confirm` to insert a row into the DB. 
If a duplicate exists it should show the Alert popup and let it stay on screen. 
And even if after this the `input1` is changed to a Successful popup one can get back to this `input1` 
and enter numbers for which there exists a duplicate in the DB. Then the Alert should display but without a `confirm` popup to create a row.

In my current situation when the first blur happens on `input1` the popup div shows and immediately hides.

How can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: You should do everything that depends on the result of the AJAX in the `$.ajax` success function, not with multiple `blur` event listeners.

Comment: `q` and `w` both refer to the same input, why do you need separate variables?

Comment: @Barmar `$.ajax` with `confirm` to create row and get last id only done one time if presed YES then its not working. After create row and get last id its only update row and no more popup `confirm` `$.ajax` to create one more row